# problem with server as well as browser build when working with SSR

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, sails.js

Facing some issue with SSR:
Error : Argument --output-hashing could not be parsed using value "false". Valid values are: "none", "all", "media", "bundles".

I have tried to upgrade the packages , but nothing happened

```
{   "name": "pictureline",   "version": "0.0.0",   "license": "MIT",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "@reactivex/rxjs": "^6.5.1",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.14",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-web-storage": "^4.1.0",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-datatable-pagination": "git+https://github.com/singhdeepme/angular2-datatable-pagination.git",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-history-api-fallback": "^2.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glyphicons": "^0.2.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-busy": "^1.4.8",
    "ng-snotify": "^4.3.1",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "ng2-go-top-button": "^6.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ng4-geoautocomplete": "^0.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroller": "^0.3.5",
    "ngx-mask": "^2.9.6",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.10.2",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "open-iconic": "^1.1.1",
    "qs-angular2-busy": "0.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.0.0",
    "save": "^2.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.6",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"   } }
```

expected a proper build

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a valid option. As stated in the message the valid values are: "none", "all", "media", "bundles".

https://angular.io/cli/build